# How to set the row size of a jquery minimal rich text editor plugin

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, rich-text-editor

I am attempting to customize a [jquery-based rich text editor](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Rich-Text-Editor-jQuery-RichText.html).
I'd like to have two on a page, one with a height of 5 rows and the other with a height of 10 rows. There are "instructions" for customizing the parameters, but I cannot figure out how to implement the instructions. I've tried, for example, placing a property and value pair as follows, but it simply breaks the control altogether. (What appears on the screen is simply a textarea control as specified by the CSS, with no rich text editing capabilities.)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#fullDescription").richText({
            height:5
        });
    });
```

I also tried `height:100px` with the same result.
The rich-text-editor *does* work if the parens on `.richText()` are left empty. But the size of the control cannot be changed and as far as I can tell, and as a client I can add rows indefinitely (the scroll bar kicks in to accommodate) rather than having the control limit the number of rows to the CSS `rows` value.

The CSS for the control is as follows (making use of bootstrap and thymeleaf):

```
<textarea class="form-control" th:field="*{fullDescription}" 
            rows="5" required>
</textarea>
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish customizing the height of the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to share, provided to me by Nam Ha Minh of codejava.net.

The Bootstrap class invocation in the `<textarea>` tag was the source of interference. Once it was removed, the height attribute worked fine. Though, I should mention, the value indicates pixels, so a larger value than 5 should be specified!

I haven't explored if the presence of *any* class tag causes interference, and that this isn't particularly about Bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

In file `richtext.min.css`, the height of `.richText .richText-editor` is 300px.

To fix your issue, change `min-height` and `height` properties.
I tried and it work for me.

```css
.richText .richText-editor {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: #fff solid 2px;
    font-family: Calibri, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: fit-content;
    outline: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)